# Python 3 Code explanation needed (for loop): Print reverse number from 10 to 1

Tags: python

output:

```
1
3 2
6 5 4
10 9 8 7
```

input:

```
start = 1
stop = 2
current_num = stop
for row in range(2, 6):
    for col in range(start, stop):
        current_num -= 1
        print(current_num, end=' ')
    print("")
    start = stop
    stop += row
    current_num = stop
```

what is the last 3 expressions do and what does each variable represent?
does anyone understand it?
I am so confused

```
    start = stop
    stop += row
    current_num = stop
```

Answer (score 1):

- `start` is a variable that stores the lower number of each row, wich means that at the end of your loop, it will be set as the number where you stopped last row (`stop`). It is used as the lower end of your print loop iteration.
- `stop`, is the number where your second loop stops, as the function `range(1 , 3)` is iterating over `[1 , 2]` for example (1 before the second parameter)
- `current_num` is set the same, as you are printing in descending order, it is set as the lowest number of your next row, and then the loop itself decrements this variable before printing it in your current row.

Basically, these 3 operations set up your variables for the next iteration of your main loop.

Answer (score 1):

Tha last 3 expressions update the new states of the variables, from the current iteration of the row-loop, to the next.
The initial set of variables are described by;

```
start = 1
stop = 2
current_num = stop
# current_sum = 2
```

For the next iteration of the row-loop we want to start counting backwards from where we last stopped + 1. (we have printed "1 ", now we want to print "3 2 ").

```
start = stop
# set start as the last value of stop, start = 2

stop += row
# increment the new stop-value with how long our last row was (row was 2 in first iteration), stop = 4.

current_num = stop
# set current_num same as the new stop value, current_num = 4.
# we can't replace current_num with stop since we count backwards using current_num (), while still keeping track of the stop value.
```

Before the next iteration of the forloop, the variables are update once again.

Try to read more about for-loops, to get the hang of how to deal with variables (which ones you need to execute the loop, and which ones you need to update for the function within the loop itself).

Hope this helped, have a nice day!